# Monitor HLS and ICY streams metadata with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, http-live-streaming, icecast

Do anyone know is it possible to continuously output the name of playing song for the HLS or ICY streams?

For ICY streams I found the possible solution: `ffmpeg -i "http://media-ice.musicradio.com/CapitalMP3" output.aac -v trace` -- with "-v trace" option it will output a lot of extra information + updates of metadata.
But for HLS this approach is not working, metadata is not refreshing when song changed.

Any help would be nice. Thanks!